# Microsoft.Cis.Monitoring.ConfigReader.DLL can't be loaded

Tags: visual-studio, azure, iis-express

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Cis.Monitoring.ConfigReader.DLL' or one of its
>   dependencies.

I'm running an Azure based web application at a large company.

I've tried the fix of forcing 64bit IISExpress. But it still happens. There were no code changes AFAIK that got this to start happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how these binaries got there in the first place, but there were several dozen binaries not referenced anywhere in the code in the .BIN folder that shouldn't have been there at all. Renaming the bin folder and recompiling solved the problem. Simply deleting it of course would have worked but renaming it gave me better feedback on what was going on.

Comment: You should accept this answer to close the question.